# Using Sphinx with Laravel 4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, sphinx

I am new to `Sphinx`. I need a query to search the given keywords through out the database tables using `Php Sphinx Mysql`.

I am using Sphinx server in `Laravel` framework.

Anyone give suggestions please.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this tutorial on how to install the SphinxQL package for Laravel:

http://packalyst.com/packages/package/mnshankar/sphinxql

**Quick installation:**

a) add into `composer.json` the requirement for `"mnshankar/sphinxql": "1.0"` and run `composer update`

b) update your `app/config/app.php` with appropriate provider and alias

```
'providers' => array(
    'mnshankar\Sphinxql\SphinxqlServiceProvider',
)

...

'aliases' => array(
    'SphinxQL' => 'mnshankar\Sphinxql\Facades\SphinxqlFacade',
)
```

c) If you need to override the default configuration options (server/port), please use the config publish command `php artisan config:publish mnshankar/sphinxql`

**Usage:**

Get acquainted with extensive documentation for the underlying library and you will have no problem with using it: http://foolcode.github.io/SphinxQL-Query-Builder/

In the end, in Laravel it is as easy as:

```
$q = SphinxQL::query()->select()
            ->from('rt_test')
            ->match('content', 'test')
            ->execute();

//debug the result or do whatever
dd(Sphinx::with($q)->get('Blog'));
```

Comment: I have did with installation.

Comment: If you have it installed, now it's up to you how you want to use it. Check the linked tutorial for example use of rt indexes and the linked docs for all available options.

Comment: I have checked the tutorial there is only one/two page. They haven't given much explanation on queries